# How to align the cursor to the left side after using printf (c linux)

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I am using printf but for some reason the cursor starts below the end of the previous line.

```
system("/bin/stty raw");

    while(true){

        char c = getchar();
        printf("%c\n", c);

    }

system ("/bin/stty cooked");
```

My output ends up looking like this.

```
Enter a value: 
kk
  kk
    kk
      kk
        kk
          kk
            kk
              kk
                kk
                  kk
                    kk
                      kk
                        **
```

Comment: Strange environment, but might it need `\r\n` instead of `\n`?

Comment: @yunnosch ya its just a simplified example. i have a way out of the loop xD and you are right. Would you mind making an answer and I can select it? \r\n worked!

Comment: Read the entire page at https://linux.die.net/man/3/cfmakeraw _very carefully_.  It's long and cryptic but if you want to use raw mode you need to understand _all_ of it.

Comment: Alternatively, switch to using [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).

Comment: @zwol I would add your input from comments to my answer, to make it more balanced over the range of complexity and flexibility. If you don't mind or make a separate answer.

Comment: You really should use [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is at least one environment which needs `\r\n` instead of `\n` in some situations.

(In case this should survive for a long time, when the comments disappear, let me mention the recommendation from comments (credits to zwol), to use ncurses.)

Answer (score 3):

Using `stty raw` turns off some output mapping options, such as `onlcr`:

> `onlcr (-onlcr)`
>                    Map (do not map) NL to CR-NL on output.

If you want that still set, adjust your `stty` call accordingly.  Alternatively, now you know why Windows uses `CRLF` (`"\r\n"`) line endings (and so do many Internet protocols); the `CR` moves the cursor to the start of line and the `LF` (aka `NL`) moves the cursor down one line in the current column.

There are advantages to using `popen("echo \"stty $(stty -g)\"", "r")` to read the current terminal settings.  It will generate a string such as

```
stty gfmt1:cflag=4b00:iflag=6b02:lflag=200005cb:oflag=3:discard=f:dsusp=19:eof=4:eol=ff:eol2=ff:erase=7f:intr=3:kill=18:lnext=16:min=1:quit=1c:reprint=12:start=11:status=14:stop=13:susp=1a:time=0:werase=17:ispeed=9600:ospeed=9600
```

(that happens to be what I get on a Mac), which you can then run to reset the mode exactly as it was before you set it to `raw`.  Setting to `cooked` may not reset everything the way it was before.

Running at the shell:

```
$ old=$(stty -g)
$ stty -a
speed 9600 baud; 65 rows; 110 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe -echok echoke -echonl echoctl
    -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
    -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel iutf8
    -ignbrk brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
    -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
    eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^X; lnext = ^V;
    min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
    stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
$ stty raw
$ speed 9600 baud; 65 rows; 110 columns;
                                                 lflags: -icanon -isig -iexten -echo -echoe -echok echoke -echonl echoctl
            -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho -pendin -nokerninfo
                                                                                -extproc
                                                                                        iflags: -istrip -icrnl -inlcr -igncr -ixon -ixoff ixany -imaxbel iutf8
                                                    ignbrk -brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
                                                                                             oflags: -opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
                          cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
                                                                                                    -dtrflow -mdmbuf
          cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
                                                                        eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^X; lnext = ^V;
                        min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
                                                                                    stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
                      $ $ $
$
```

After typing `stty raw` (and <kbd>return</kbd>), I typed `stty -a` <kbd>control-J</kbd> to get the indented output.  The 3 `$` prompts included me typing `stty "$old"` <kbd>control-J</kbd> and hitting <kbd>return</kbd>.  When reformatted a bit, the settings in `raw` mode are:

```
speed 9600 baud; 65 rows; 110 columns;
lflags: -icanon -isig -iexten -echo -echoe -echok echoke -echonl echoctl
        -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho -pendin -nokerninfo
        -extproc
iflags: -istrip -icrnl -inlcr -igncr -ixon -ixoff ixany -imaxbel iutf8
        ignbrk -brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: -opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
        -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
        eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^X; lnext = ^V;
        min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
        stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
```